# CakePHP model association based on field values?

Tags: cakephp, model

I've got three tables (there's actually several more, but I only need the three for this problem).  Applications, Appattrs and Appcats.  In CakePHP parlance (as best as I can since I'm still learning the framenwork) Applications hasMany Appattrs and Appattrs belongsTo Applications.  Easy.

The problem comes when I want to associate Appattrs and Appcat - the association is predicated on a field value and a corresponding foreign key in Appattrs.  For instance:

If appattrs.type = 'appcatid' then appattrs.value would point to a record in the Appcat table.

The appattrs table holds static data appattrs.type='dateadded' and value='201201011300' as well as foreign key references.  I'd rather not get into a discussion as to why data is stored this way, I just want to figure out how to create associations that will let me pull an application record, the associated attr records and then an attr record with its associated row from the appropriate table.  Dynamically.

It seems to me that I should be able to create a model based on a query and then associate that model - I just can't seem to figure out how to do that.

--

If I need to post schema for the three tables, I can.  I can also post my current model code, but honestly, right now it's just association variables so I don't think it'll get anyone anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thow I do not understand the logic behind this design, I thing what you are looking for
is [Creating and Destroying associations on the fly](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly).

On this section of CakePHP Docs, it describes how you can associate models from within the corresponding controller.

So, for example, when you want to save specific data to `Appattr` model you can do some data checking and create your association using `bind()` method.

A very abstract approach to the above would be something like this

```
public function yourmethod() {
     ...
     if ($this->request->data['Appattr']['type'] == 'sometype') {
         $this->Appattr->bindModel(
                array(/*Your association*/ => array(/* Your attributes...*/)
         );
         /* Rest of the logic follows */
     }
 }
```

This way you get your job done, but it's very possible to end up having very complicated
data in your database and thus having very complicated code.

I hope this helps

Comment: After a bit of struggling, I ultimately wound up using bindModel to create associations on the fly - and although your answer didn't explicitly answer my question it got me headed in the correct direction.